# Loading input/output folders with .npy extension in PyTorch

Tags: numpy, pytorch, dataset, autoencoder

I am new in using pytorch and in ML in general.

I am building encoder-decoder architecture, similar to autoencoder, but input and output are different numpy arrays.
I have two folders “input” and “output”, where input and output pairs are store in .npy format.
At the moment I called each pair of input and output with the same name.
So, for example, input/output files of pair 1 has same name, but stored in different folders.

I am not sure how to use how to use DatasetFolder, so my dataset will become X,Y which I will be able to split in train/test and feed to the model.

Thanks

Comment: Hi @Dulat Yussupaliyev, welcome. Please see [How to create minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to increase the possiblity of getting an answer.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know even how my code should look like for this task, to put it here.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone will face same issue.

```
class En_De_coder_dataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, in_dir, out_dir, transform=None):
        self.in_dir = in_dir
        self.out_dir = out_dir
        self.transform = transform
        
        
    def __len__(self):
        return len(os.listdir(self.in_dir))

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        input = torch.from_numpy(np.load(self.in_dir + '/grid_aug_' + str(index) + '.npy')).float()
        output = torch.from_numpy(np.load(self.out_dir + '/grid_aug_' + str(index) + '.npy')).float()
        if self.transform:
            input = self.transform(input)
            output = self.transform(output)
        
        return (input, output)
```